# How to check if loadfunctionlibrary have loaded libraries successfully in UFT during run time.

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am using loadfunctionlibrary to load few libraries. I notice that the functions in the library which i intend to load, failed to get called when i try to call them in my driver script. How do i check if the library is really loaded or not.
What could be the possible issue for this behavior ?

Comment: Can you show the code that's not working?  Have you ensured the user executing the scripts has access to all required network paths? Not misspelled it? Checked that the functions are built correctly without syntax errors that may cause the load step to fail?  You need to provide more information in order for people to be able to offer help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be due to some syntax error in those files. Open the file in QTP and press `ctrl+F7` to check the syntax.

If there is no syntax error, check the filename and file path etc.
Include a `print "fileA is loaded successfully"` in each file - so that you can check if every gets loaded successfully at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Possible checks:

1. Attach all the function libraries in the Resources -> Settings tab and check if any syntax errors.
2. Run your script with attached libraries and enable "Proceed to Next Step" and observe if any "Run Error" reported.

Answer (score 1):

Use **On error resume next** before the script and check for **err.number** after **loadfunctionlibrary** method. If it is **0** that means function got loaded successfully.